# how to name database column appropriately

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

In excel file, I have columns like this; 11.01-12.00, 12.01-13.00, ..., 29.01-30.00. And the content of the column is the price. I want to store a price in many ranges in MySQL like excel column.

Do I have to create a table like this or Do your guys have any better way please guide me?

Comment: Store it as an integer in a column called ‘price’?

Comment: Can you provide me an example, please?

Comment: Do each column imm the excel file have a price? And hence there would be a price corresponding to each range for eg range: 11.01-12.00 price: 11.50, range:29.01-30.00 price:29.70 and so on

Comment: Yes, each column has a price. What should I name my database column?

Comment: What does the range represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option may be to define a column `price_range` or `prices` as json column and store the data as key=>value pairs for eg: '11.01-12:00'=> 11.50

In your migration file for the table, add a column

```php
$table->json('prices');
```

And in your model class, specify to cast `prices` column as array.

```php
class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = ['prices' => 'array'];

    //... rest of the class code
}
```

By specifying the cast, you can now use associative array to store data on the column, you can work in php arrays to store and update data.

```php
$myModel = new MyModel;

$myModel->prices = [
    '11.01-12.00' => 11.50,
    '12.01-13.00' => 12.35,
    //...
    '29.01-30.00' => 29.82,
];

$myModel->save();
```

To update data

```php
$myModel = MyModel::find(5);

$newPrices = [
    '11.01-12.00' => 11.20,
    '12.01-13.00' => 12.63,
    //...
    '29.01-30.00' => 29.05,
]

$myModel->update(['prices' => $newPrices]);

/OR to update price for a specific price range

$myModel->update(['prices->11.01-12.00' => 11.25]);
```

Laravel docs:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment-json-columns
- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#updating-json-columns

Answer (score 1):

In your database table migration file, define a column called `price` to hold your value.

```
$table->integer('price');
```

Store your price as the lowest denominator for your currency performing whatever arithmetic is required to perform the conversions in/out of the database.

There is no need for you to create individual columns for different prices.

**Edit 1**

Based on your question update that the information is in an excel file, you'll want to make use of a package such as [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html) (no point reinventing the wheel) to perform your import.

Nice tutorial for importing an excel file [here](https://www.webslesson.info/2019/02/import-excel-file-in-laravel.html)

Comment: I think I might explain the question confusing. In an excel file, I have columns like this; 11.01-12.00, 12.01-13.00, ..., 29.01-30.00. And the content of the column is the price. I want to migrate the file to MySQL database. What should I do?

Comment: @Willywongka Yeah, that's a pretty important piece of information to omit from your question. You might want to update it to explain you're importing data from an excel file.

Comment: Sorry for keeping you confusing.

Comment: @Willywongka No worries. Made an update which should help.

Comment: I think you can use varchar column, be fore inserting price range  in varchar column, convert to varchar

Comment: @SivaKoteswaraRao You could do, but how would you perform calculations on that column in the database?